# PHP array in two different variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that produces an xml file and create records for every product in my database. The xml file has a field named size that gets the values from the code bellow. Is it possible to modify the code bellow so to create a second variable like $size_str to store for every product the colors of the product by choosing the id_attribute_group=1 for size and id_attribute_group=2 for color;

I'm not a programmer so any help will be very appreciated.

```
$size_attribute=1;

foreach ($products as $product){
    $quantity = Product::getQuantity($product['id_product']);
    //Export size
    $checking = "SELECT  al.name AS attribute_name FROM "._DB_PREFIX_."product_attribute pa
    LEFT JOIN "._DB_PREFIX_."product_attribute_combination pac ON pac.id_product_attribute = pa.id_product_attribute
    LEFT JOIN "._DB_PREFIX_."attribute a ON a.id_attribute = pac.id_attribute
    LEFT JOIN "._DB_PREFIX_."attribute_group ag ON ag.id_attribute_group = a.id_attribute_group
    LEFT JOIN "._DB_PREFIX_."attribute_lang al ON (a.id_attribute = al.id_attribute AND al.id_lang =".$id_lang.")
    LEFT JOIN "._DB_PREFIX_."attribute_group_lang agl ON (ag.id_attribute_group = agl.id_attribute_group AND agl.id_lang =".$id_lang.")
    WHERE pa.id_product = ".$product['id_product']." and ag.id_attribute_group=".$size_attribute." OR ag.id_attribute_group=".$color_attribute." ORDER BY attribute_name";
    $sz = Db::getInstance()->executeS($checking);
    $size_str = "";
    foreach ($sz as $key => $value) {$size_str = $size_str.','.$value['attribute_name'];}
    $size_str = substr($size_str, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need only to add more to the `SELECT al.name AS attribute_name, al.size as size  FROM....`  or use `*` to get everything.

You can write like this as a test(to check you get what you want):

```
$sql = 'SELECT al.name AS attribute_name, al.size as size  FROM...’;
if ($row = Db::getInstance()->getRow($sql))
    echo $row['attribute_name'].' :: '.$row['size'];
```

I just guessed that the size will be in al, but if its in another table then you can write that table <table_name>.size

Comment: Thaks for your reply.